# How to solve unrecognized rule and fatal parse error

Tags: cygwin, lex

I'm very new to lex, and have tried to make a scanner. Here's my code:

The definition and rule part

```
identifier              ([A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*)
digit                   ([0-9])
integer                 ({digit}+)
float           ({integer}"."[0-9]+)
delimiter               ([.,:;()\[\]{}])
arithmetic              ([+-*/])
relational              ([<>=])
string                  (\"(\"\"|[^"\n])*\")
commentLine     (\%[^\n]*)
commentLeft     ({%)
commentRight        (%})

%x COMMENT

%option noyywrap

%%

 {delimiter;}       {tokenChar(yytext[0]);}
 {arithmetic;}      {tokenChar(yytext[0]);}
 {relational;}      {tokenChar(yytext[0]);}

"<="                    { token('<='); }
">="                    { token('>='); }
"not="                  { token('not='); }
":="            { token(':='); }

"not"                   { token('not'); }
"and"                   { token('and'); }
"or"                    { token('or'); }

"array"                 { token(ARRAY); }
"begin"                 { token(BEGIN); }
"bool"                  { token(BOOL); }
"char"                  { token(CHAR); }
"const"                 { token(CONST); }
"decreasing"            { token(DECREASING); }
"default"               { token(DEFAULT); }
"do"                    { token(DO); }
"else"                  { token(ELSE); }
"end"                   { token(END); }
"exit"                  { token(EXIT); }
"false"                 { token(FALSE); }
"for"                   { token(FOR); }
"function"              { token(FUNCTION); }
"get"                   { token(GET); }
"if"                    { token(IF); }
"int"                   { token(INT); }
"loop"                  { token(LOOP); }
"of"                    { token(OF); }
"put"                   { token(PUT); }
"procedure"             { token(PROCEDURE); }
"real"                  { token(REAL); }
"result"                { token(RESULT); }
"return"                { token(RETURN); }
"skip"                  { token(SKIP); }
"string"                { token(STRING); }
"then"                  { token(THEN); }
"true"                  { token(TRUE); }
"var"                   { token(VAR); }
"when"                  { token(WHEN); }

 {integer}  {
    tokenInteger("integer", atoi(yytext));
}

 {identifier} {
    tokenString("identifier", yytext);
    table -> insert(yytext);
}

 {float}    {
    tokenFloat("float", yytext);
 }

 {string}    {
    char s[MAX_LINE_LENG] = {0};
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < yyleng - 1; ++i){
        if (yytext[i] == '"')
            ++i;
        s[idx++] = yytext[i];
    }
    tokenString("string", s);
}

 {commentLine}  {
    LIST;
}

 {% { 
    LIST;
    BEGIN(COMMENT);
}

<COMMENT>[^\n]  {
    LIST;
}

<COMMENT>\n {   
    LIST;
    printf("%d: %s", linenum, buf);
    linenum++;
    buf[0] = '\0';
}

<COMMENT> {commentRight}    {
        LIST;
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
    }

\n  {
    LIST;
    printf("%d: %s", linenum++, buf);
    buf[0] = '\0';
}

[ \t]*  {
    LIST;
}

.   {
    LIST;
    printf("%d:%s\n", linenum+1, buf);
    printf("bad character:'%s'\n",yytext);
    exit(-1);
}
%%
```

And the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *yyin;
    if (argc > 0){
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!yyin){
            printf("Failed to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

Since I'm still trying, there should be a lot of mistakes. However, when I type `lex scanner.l` it only says:

> scanner.l:209: unrecognized rule
> scanner.l:209: fatal parse error

Line 209 is the `%%` after rules sections. Is my definition incorrect? Not sure where's the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You have made quite a few novice errors in your file, which are all typos. The best way of debugging this kind of problem is to cut out lines from your code until the error goes away (perhaps using the binary chop method). Doing  this you will rapidly find exactly which lines are causing problems. I will not list every fault you made, but I can make this work in lex/flex quite easily in a few minutes.

The mistakes I found were:

- the lex patterns MUST start in the first column. Some of yours had a space before them.
- the lex action rules MUST NOT be in the first column. Some of yours did have characters in column one (particularly when it was a closing <kbd>}</kbd>).
- The <kbd>}</kbd> is a lex meta-character (meaning it is part of the lex syntax). This means you have to be careful when using it in your patterns. You should escape <kbd>}</kbd> with a <kbd>\</kbd> when it should be matched as itself. In several places you have not.
- The minus <kbd>-</kbd> is also a lex meta character in character sets. If the set is to match the actual <kbd>-</kbd> and does not indicate a character range then it also must be escaped by <kbd>\</kbd>.
- You put a semicolon <kbd>;</kbd> in the name of a pattern, which is not correct. For example `{delimiter;}`.
- Lex thinks you have two possible matches for a bare newline character <kbd>\n</kbd>. Check this carefully.

However the BIGGEST MISTAKE you made, and one made by so many students, is to try and implement the whole thing IN ONE GO. Very poor. Experienced software engineers know to do it one piece at a time. Start with a small subset of your language, get that to work, and then add a few more statements and continue until it all works. Start, perhaps, with operators or keywords and add the other parts piecemeal. Then you know where the errors lie. This is why Stack Overflow likes small reproducable examples and not whole code bases.